# Snapping to sketch' vertices while editing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, editing, snapping

I'm trying to digitize buildings in QGIS and encountered a problem:
after digitizing several vertices in a sketch, I want to place my final vertex in accordance with the first one - i.e 'square and finish' (in ArcMap).

Is there a way to snap\refer to a previous sketched vertices in QGIS?

---

The only solution I found involved creating features and then using its vertices as snapping anchors for precise sketching.

[image]

Comment: That would result in a faulty geometry, why would you want to do that?

Comment: You are digitizing your building like you would with a "closed" polyline ? is there a specific reason for that that prevent you digitizing them as regular polygon ? (meaning using only 4 non overlapping vertex for 4 sided polygon)

Comment: Hi @Erik, I've must explained myself unclear: the final vertex should be placed in the lower left star. Its position should be perpendicular to the lower dashed line.

Comment: The questioned is addressed in this [PR](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/36200). Hope it'll be implemented soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snapping to sketch' geometry is now available in development version and soon in 3.14, thanks to [this PR](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/36200#issuecomment-634006684). Here's how to do it:

1. Create a permanent vector layer.
2. Toggle editing.
3. Add polygon feature
4. Snapping toolbar > Self-Snapping
   [image]

Answer (score 6):

There is no "snap to sketch" equivalent in QGIS, unfortunately. There are a couple of ways to deal with this situation, but each involve a couple of steps.

Go to **View** > **Toolbars**, and enable the **Shape Digitizing Toolbar**. One of the tools is for creating rectangles. There are several different options within that tool. For more precision, you may want to use the **Add rectangle from 3 points** tool.

[image: rectangle digitizing tools]

Now as you digitize shapes, they will be perfectly orthogonal. What about L-shaped buildings, though? Or more complex shapes? For that, we can combine other tools from the **Advanced Digitizing Toolbar**.

1. **Reshape Features** [image: reshape features icon]

With your rectangle feature created, you can use its vertices, segments, and angles to reshape.

[image: reshaping process]

2. **Advanced Digitizing Panel** [image: advanced digitizing icon]

In conjunction with the reshaping, you can also take advantage of the **Parallel** and **Perpendicular** modes on the Advanced Digitizing Panel. With advanced digitizing tools active, you can also press `p` on the keyboard to toggle through these.

Once you enable either parallel or perpendicular, your next click will select a segment to refer to, but will not place a vertex. Once clicked, your digitizing angle will be constrained. Additionally, helper lines will appear to show where your line will match up with existing lines.

[image: perpendicular digitizing]

3. **Merge Selected Features** [image: merge features icon]

If you've got a simple L-shaped house, you can also digitize two overlapping rectangles, select them, and then merge them together.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer @JoshC.